# Where is the YouTube API V1 Dashboard?

Tags: c#, youtube-api, dashboard

I have an application still in use, which uses Version 1.9 of the YouTube .Net API. It still works for older YouTube accounts but I'm porting it to Version 3 of the API to support new YouTube accounts.

Last time I looked, the application had logged over 14,000 uploads. This information was available at the original, but now deprecated, [Google Dashboard](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard). I haven't seen any statistics for over six months and have no idea how it's travelling.

The new [developer's console](https://cloud.google.com/console/project) used for Version 3 of the API does not show any data or information for my existing application.

Does anyone know where I can find the upload statistics associated with my older application which uses Version  1.9 of the YouTube API?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I always had the wrong URL but it appears to be working perfectly now. The previous URL was missing the SSL component. 31,000 uploads!

https://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/gwt/index.html